# jQuery Masonry plugin: images not resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, masonry

I am creating a gallery of images using David deSandro Masonry plugin however the container tile do not resizes according to the images.

My project can be seen here:

```
[https://codepen.io/viteresa/pen/KqzPWV][1]
```

(using as example internet images)

Any help to detect the error is greatly appreciated as I am stuck for a while...
Best regards